# HTML5 webpage with doctype but no opening html tag

Tags: html, tags

I've found HTML5 tutorial that seems to be written correctly but when I go into developer settings of tutorial page i see this:

[image: Code snippet image]

There is no `<html>` tag, I am very curious if this is indented or some kind of technique I don't know of. Then again author of page seems kind of knowledgeable and this is very protruding.

So is this correct?

Webpage in question:
http://how2html.pl/znacznik-html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The omission of the `<html>` tag is entirely valid in this case. To quote from [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics#the-html-element):

> An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.

Whether or not this is recommended is debatable, but it will certainly validate without issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they don't have `<html>` at the start but they do have `</html>` at the end of the HTML file. This isn't correct and this isn't intended.

By standard, a HTML file should have `<html>` tag at start, just after the `!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought.